# Can "nm" determine whether the undefined symbol is a function or a variable?

Tags: linux, nm, symbol-table

Is it possible to distinguish whether a symbol reported by `nm` is a function symbol or a variable symbol?

For example, if `nm` reports that there is an undefined symbol

```
U the_undefined_symbol
```

How can I know whether the_undefined_symbol is an undefined function or an undefined variable?

Comment: Also see [nm(1) - list symbols from object files](https://linux.die.net/man/1/nm).

Comment: What exactly should I see in that documentation?

Comment: To answer questions like [nm reports the line “i cos” - what does it mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54053396/608639)

Comment: "U" - The symbol is undefined. That is all the documentation says about U symbols. Could you please provide more information?